# PHP show data using date range

Tags: php, mysql

Here it's, I've got the answer.

I just change in track_reports.php to be :

```
if (isset($_POST['chkOtdate']))
                    {
                        $date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
                        $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];
                        if (empty($bagianWhere))
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= "ot_date between '$date_from' and '$date_to'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= " AND ot_date between '$date_from' and '$date_to'";
                        }
                    }
```

and now nothing problem the code can be run smoothly.
Thanks for your helps friends.
Appreciate with your suggestions and comments.

---

I have a trouble with my code below :

1. view_report.php

We can view report based on badge_id, employee_name and ot_date (with a range).
When I try to find using badge_id and employee_name no problem, data showed. But when I try to find using date range, error found. the error is : `: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in on line WarningC:\xampp\htdocs\siix_dev\overtime\track_reports.php327`

```
<form method="post" action="track_reports.php" name="form">
                    <table id="mytable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkBadge" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox')"> <font class="category">Badge ID</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input id="textBox" class="text sign" type="text" name="badge_id">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkEmp" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox2')"> <font class="category">Employee Name</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input id="textBox2" class="text sign" type="text" name="employee_name">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="chkOtdate" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox3')" onChange="apply(this.checked, 'textBox4')"> <font class="category">OT Date</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <font class="category">From</font> <input id="textBox3" class="text sign" type="text" name="date_from" ><font class="category"> To</font> <input id="textBox4" class="text sign" type="text" name="date_to" >
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

1. track_reports.php

   ```
                   $bagianWhere = "";

                   if (isset($_POST['chkBadge']))
                   {
                       $badge_id = $_POST['badge_id'];
                       if (empty($bagianWhere))
                       {
                           $bagianWhere .= "badge_id = '$badge_id'";
                       }
                   }

                   if (isset($_POST['chkEmp']))
                   {
                      $employee_name = $_POST['employee_name'];
                      if (empty($bagianWhere))
                       {
                           $bagianWhere .= "employee_name LIKE '$employee_name'";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           $bagianWhere .= " AND employee_name LIKE '$employee_name'";
                       }
                   }

                   if (isset($_POST['chkOtdate']))
                   {
                       $date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
                       $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

                       $query=mysql_query("select badge_id, employee_name from t_submissions where ot_date between '$date_from' and '$date_to'");
                       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                           echo $row['badge_id'];
                           echo $row['employee_name'];
                       }
                   }

                   $query = "SELECT * FROM t_submissions WHERE ".$bagianWhere;
                   $hasil = mysql_query($query);
                   echo "                      
                   <div id='main' class='wrapper'>
                                   <div class='content-area'>

                   <table cellspacing='0' class='font'>";
                   echo "<tr><th class='th'>Badge ID</th><th class='th'>Employee Name</th><th class='th'>OT Date</th><th class='th'>Department</th><th class='th'>OT From</th><th class='th'>OT To</th><th class='th'>Remarks</th><th class='th'>Submissions By</th><th class='th'>Acknowledged By</th><th class='th'>Approved By</th></tr>";
                   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
                   {
                      echo "<tr><td class='td'>".$data['badge_id']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['employee_name']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['ot_date']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['dept_name']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['ot_from']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['ot_to']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['remarks']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['submission_by']."</td></tr>";
                   }
                   echo "</table>
                   <br>
                   <input type='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   ";

                   ?>
   ```

Someone can help me ?
Appreciate with your helps.

Comment: Let's know what's error itself.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: this is the error sir : : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in on line

WarningC:\xampp\htdocs\siix_dev\overtime\track_reports.php327

Comment: In what format did you enter the dates into your form?  As text boxes whose value is used as a direct comparison against the database field, it should be in the same format as that field (if the column is of type `DATE`, then MySQL requires such literals to by `'yyyy-mm-dd'`).

Comment: To catch the error, you should test `$hasil` to see if the query succeeded before calling `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: sir, the example format that i make is : 02-May-2012.

Comment: And what data type is the `ot_date` column?

Comment: same like I describe before : 02-May-2012, date format : "d-M-Y"

Comment: In that case, it's a string type?  You can't use `BETWEEN ... AND` to compare strings in this manner...

Comment: I using varchar type sir. I've tried with a single search without badge_id and employee_name textbox and it works. But when I try to combine it to be 1, found that error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the datatype of ot_date is **datetime** or not ? perhaps you used **varchar**

Comment: what is the datatype of ot_date

Answer (score 0):

In your comments above, you state that the `ot_date` column in which you are storing your "dates" has type `VARCHAR`.  Therefore MySQL doesn't recognise its contents as dates at all, but rather treats them like a sequence of meaningless (to it) characters (such as a word).

The best thing you could do is to alter your database so that such dates are stored in a format that MySQL recognises as a date, like the `DATE` data type.  To do this without losing your existing data:

1. Rename the existing column and add a new one in its place:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t_submissions
     CHANGE ot_date ot_date_old VARCHAR(size),
     ADD    ot_date DATE [NOT NULL] AFTER ot_date_old;
   ```
2. Copy the contents of the old column into the new one, as dates:

   ```
   UPDATE t_submissions SET ot_date = STR_TO_DATE(ot_date_old, '%d-%b-%Y');
   ```
3. Verify that the new column contains the expected data:

   ```
   SELECT ot_date, ot_date_old FROM t_submissions;
   ```
4. Delete the old column (optional):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t_submissions DROP ot_date_old;
   ```

Next, to make your query work, MySQL needs to know how to convert the submitted dates into dates rather than treating them as strings:

```
SELECT badge_id, employee_name FROM t_submissions
WHERE ot_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', ?) AND STR_TO_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', ?)
```

Note that I have used `?` in place of the date variables because, as mentioned in my comments above, your code is currently subject to SQL injection and you **really** should be passing such variables to MySQL as parameters to a prepared statement (as such, they wouldn't get evaluated for SQL).  Read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) for more information.

Also note that your current form **requires** the user to enter the dates into the text boxes in the specified format, or else the query will fail.  You would be better off requiring the user to select date parts from drop-downs (or some form of calendar control) and/or perform validation in order to ensure that submitted dates are in the correct format.

Finally, you should test the result of your query to see if it succeeded before attempting to read a recordset that might not exist (as indeed it didn't in this case).

Comment: Here it's, I've got the answer.

I just change in track_reports.php to be :

    if (isset($_POST['chkOtdate']))
      {
       $date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
       $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];
       if (empty($bagianWhere))
       {
        $bagianWhere .= "ot_date between '$date_from' and '$date_to'";
       }
       else
       {
        $bagianWhere .= " AND ot_date between '$date_from' and '$date_to'";
       }
      }

and now nothing problem the code can be run smoothly.
Thanks for your helps friends.
Appreciate with your suggestions and comments.